# How would you describe "a" in these two sentences?

Tags: meaning, grammar, prepositions

How would you describe "a" in these two sentences?

> Organo a canne - Pipe organ. 
>   Giocare a biliardo - Playing (to play) billiards.

Usually "a" means "to".

> Tornate a Parigi? - Do you come back to Paris?

It is a bit weird for me to think of "organ to pipes" and "playing to billiards".
Please explain.

Comment: There's very rarely a perfect correspondence of prepositions in different languages.

Comment: Translating Italian expression into English and pondering about the English expressions won't get you anywhere. :) Italian, as any other language, has its own rules and uses.

Comment: A volte la "a" è usata per indicare un'importante caratteristica di un oggetto: "organo a canne" per distinguere da "organo elettrico"; significherebbe "che funziona con...". Ma ci sono altri casi: "lasagne al forno" sono lasagne *cotte nel* forno. Molte volte si tratta di francesismi. E' bene usare quella costruzione solo se si è certi che sia di uso comune perchè non è una costruzione normale nella lingua italiana.

Answer (score 6):

The English preposition *to* corresponds to several Italian prepositions:

> I'm going to the sea — Vado al mare
>   John came to the rescue – Giovanni è venuto in soccorso
>   Alice came to repair the car – Alice è venuta per riparare l'auto
>   Philip is an advisor to the boss — Filippo è un consigliere del capo

Conversely, in order to render the Italian preposition *a*, you have to use different English constructions, like in the examples you mention.

There's rarely perfect correspondence between prepositions in different languages. Italian *da* can mean *from* or *by* (or also other English prepositions), depending on the context.

In the construction *organo a canne*, the preposition *a* introduces a “complemento di mezzo”: “organo che suona per mezzo di canne”. English uses a different rendering: pipe organ is “organ that produces sound by pipes”. Similarly, *sedia a rotelle* is wheelchair; not so similarly, *andare a piedi* is “going on foot”.

Comment: What does "a" in Organo a canne?
Organ to pipes seems like a weird translation.
Does "a" also mean something else than "to"?

Comment: @Hank Also “sedia a rotelle”, "andare a piedi" and other similar usages; it's a “complemento di mezzo”. So “organo a canne” is "organo che suona per mezzo di canne”. I'm unsure why you aren't surprised that the English translation uses “pipe” (Italian: tubo) instead of "cane” (Italian: canna).